# How to create files and folders in the user's visible storage of the Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create files and folders in the internal storage of the phone, the same place where Documents, Pictures and Music folders are located. Is it possible?

If it isn't, can I create files inside those folders? For what I read, it's possible, by getting the StorageFolder from the KnownFolders class, but I need permission to access it. Where do I declare this capability? 
According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464936.aspx) you need to declare it inside a package manifest, but I can't find it inside my Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't do it. It's imposible to create shared files between apps (only in sky).  You can create files only in internal storage for your application.

Comment: By sky you mean SkyDrive? Then how do I create files there?

Comment: @wm1sr, not only skydrive. Also you can use DropBox, for example. But OneDrive (ex SkyDrive) most applicable for WinPhone. Information about interaction with OneDrive easy enough to find in the internet.